# Checkbox auto checks on field click

Tags: javascript, pdf, checkbox, signature

I have a PDF form which includes a digital signature box. I would like for a checkbox to be checked as soon as a user clicks the signature box to sign the document using Javascript, help would be appreciated, thanks.
Only Javascript
NO HTML please.

Comment: Do you have any existing markup you can share with us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would add this line to the script doing the signing:

```
this.getField("myCheckBox").value = "Yes" ;
```

assuming that the return value of the checkbox is "Yes"; you'd have to adjust the field name and the return value.

The question is, where exactly to add the code, and what to do if the signing action fails.